# R does not exist - R cannot be resolved to a variable, No resource found that matches given name

Tags: java, android, xml, r.java-file

My project does not have an R.java-file. I understand it should be autogenerated, but it isn't.
In my .java-files I get the error message "R cannot be resolved to a variable" whenever an object
of the R-class is refered to, for instance in a line like this:

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.myform);
```

...

I have an .xml-file called myform.xml. It contains the following code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@id/message_field"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter a message here." >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

It renders this error message:

"No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with given name '@id/message_field')  "

Is this not the definition of message_field? If not, how do I know what it refers to?

Comment: Did you import android.R?

Comment: post full XML layout and activity class.

Comment: I have added import of android.R. It did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the + prefix. 
You have to use `android:id="@+id/message_field"` because you are declaring a new id for the view

Comment: I've done this, and it solves the problem for the xml file. The other problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

Change the

```
android:id="@id/message_field"
```

to

```
android:id="@+id/message_field"
```

the `@id` is used to reference an existing element with such id, while `@+id` used to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced this line...

```
   android:id="@id/message_field"
```

With this....

```
  android:id="@+id/message_field"
```

And check that you didn't import

```
        android.R.java
```

instead of

```
         R.java
```

Answer (score 0):

`@id/message_field` is mostly used by relative layouts to reference the id you already created above. You need to use `android:id="@+id/message_field"`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers above it is also good to note that both Eclipse and Android Studio will complain about the R file if there is any errors in your XML resources. As for adding the '+' it is a good habit to do that with all your id declarations. It is legal to declare an id without the '+' but it must be declared somewhere else in the file as a new id.